# PHP elseif - WordPress - New To Programming

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

```
{{
    if( sfprice_administrator_applicable() && sfprice_get_administrator_price($product) > 0 )
        $price = sfprice_get_administrator_price($product);
    return $price; 
}
{   elseif( sfprice_resellerplus_applicable() && sfprice_get_resellerplus_price($product) > 0 )
        $price = sfprice_get_resellerplus_price($product);
    return $price;
}
{    elseif( sfprice_reseller_applicable() && sfprice_get_reseller_price($product) > 0 )
        $price = sfprice_get_reseller_price($product);
    return $price;
}
{   elseif( sfprice_corporateplus_applicable() && sfprice_get_corporateplus_price($product) > 0 )
        $price = sfprice_get_corporateplus_price($product);
    return $price;
}
{   elseif( sfprice_corporate_applicable() && sfprice_get_corporate_price($product) > 0 )
        $price = sfprice_get_corporate_price($product);
    return $price;
}
{   else( sfprice_smallbusiness_applicable() && sfprice_get_smallbusiness_price($product) > 0 )
        $price = sfprice_get_smallbusiness_price($product);
    return $price;
}}
```

I am sure that this is very wrong but i am extremely new to programming so i would appreciate direction on how this should have been coded?

I understand my issue is with the if/elseif/else statement structure. But i am unsure how to properly format the information.

Comment: From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php)

Comment: No this breaks the entire site; if i have only 1 if statement it works perfectly with everything else.

Comment: I'm of the opinion that if you need to use an `elseif` you should probably be using a `switch` instead.

Comment: @Blake You can't always use `switch` statements if you have many conditions. A `switch` will only let you choose one case, where as if you have many conditions, a `switch` won't do the job.

Comment: Was speaking generally, in this case specifically since they are going to `return` on every if eval that is true, might as well just have only if statements. It'd be way easier to read, too. Write code so you (and anyone else) save the most cost from the most valuable resource.. humans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is how you bracket your `if`-statements. How they are bracketed and formatted below is how it should look.

Use this code instead

```
if (sfprice_administrator_applicable() && sfprice_get_administrator_price($product) > 0 ) {
    $price = sfprice_get_administrator_price($product);
    return $price; 
} elseif (sfprice_resellerplus_applicable() && sfprice_get_resellerplus_price($product) > 0 ) {
    $price = sfprice_get_resellerplus_price($product);
    return $price;
} elseif (sfprice_reseller_applicable() && sfprice_get_reseller_price($product) > 0 ) {
    $price = sfprice_get_reseller_price($product);
    return $price;
} elseif (sfprice_corporateplus_applicable() && sfprice_get_corporateplus_price($product) > 0 ) {
    $price = sfprice_get_corporateplus_price($product);
    return $price;
} elseif (sfprice_corporate_applicable() && sfprice_get_corporate_price($product) > 0 ) {
    $price = sfprice_get_corporate_price($product);
    return $price;
} else (sfprice_smallbusiness_applicable() && sfprice_get_smallbusiness_price($product) > 0 ) {
    $price = sfprice_get_smallbusiness_price($product);
    return $price;
}
```

Note that PHP runs in a way that selects the first `elseif` that returns true.

Comment: Ah so the brackets needed to be set after the elseif statements and then return $price outside of the brackets after each statement so that if it returned true then it would return that price?

Comment: The brackets are to be placed as the code given in my answer, yes. But the `return $price;` is inside the brackets! If you look, the closing-bracket is on the next line, just before the `elseif`-statement.

Comment: I've been looking at this too long apparently everything is running together! But yes i do see it now. Thank you very much I appreciate the help there.

Comment: Happy to help! We all started somewhere ;)

Comment: Kind of hard to play "spot the mistake" without any errors. What does your `error_log` say?

Comment: Ok issue deals with the final Else statement. I am not familiar with how to have it loop back to WooCommerce default price table. Are you familiar with WooCommerce by chance?                                                                                                                                                                                                  syntax error, unexpected '{' in /functions.php on line 233

Comment: Oh, hehe. The thing is that your last `else` is checking for a parameter to be true or false. An `else`-statement can't do that, you need a final `elseif` instead of the `else`, that should do the trick. `else` is a standard case that is run if nothing of the `if`/`elseif`-statements returns true.

Comment: Great! Works again :) now my simple products have a variable price by user role! Now i just need to fix my variation product pricing by user role. Ill see if i can apply what you've taught me to fix that section as well

Comment: Don't hesitate if you have any more questions! As long as you give it a try, most people on StackOverflow is willing to help - but trying out some on your own and providing the necessary code is very key when asking a question :) Hope you'll figure it out!